# Key decryption error when integrating with SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, reporting-services

I have a SQL Server 2012 reporting Services in native mode. The report server url is:

```
http//hodentekwin7/ReportServer_Kailua
```

This which works fine.

I have SharePoint 2010 installed it is working fine, i.e. I can access Central administration. So far no problem.

I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 for SharePoint Integrated mode, and have been able in SharePoint Adminsitration to:

- Get database access with my login credentials
- Successfully added to the WSS_WPG membership
- Specified activation and deactivation in all site collections

However, when I try to set the Report Server site settings I get this error:

> The report server cannot decrypt the symmetric key that is used to access sensitive or encrypted data in a report server database. You must either restore a backup key or delete all encrypted content. (rsReportServerDisabled) Get Online Help
>   Bad Data. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090005)

Well, SQL Server 2008 R2's Configuration Manager is not even accessed even once to set up any kind of encryption. I cannot even access the server.

The Microsoft link for this error helps is a page which is not available.

The Report Server is working but cannot be configured. The Report server databases are present. SSRS 2008 R2 was never configured through the Configuration Manager of RS.

Some tips on MS Site regarding "deleting all encrypted keys" requires access to SSRS Configuration tool (which is not available for SSRS with SharePoint).

Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer. I deleted all encrypted content. The funny thing is it was a fresh installed, never used service, where did the encrypted content come from? Perhaps out of the box item!